# How to capture repeated pattern in logstash(5.4.0) grok?

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I would appreciate if someone can help me out with logstash grok.

Given a log like below ,

```
IN 192.168.11.2 IN 192.168.11.3
```

My goal is to put the ip address into **array** using grok. List of ip is dynamic and possible to extend more than 2.

```
e.g
tmp = [
"192.168.11.2", "192.168.11.3"
]
```

However, if I use a filter like below it ends up in single field.

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "(?<tmp>(IN %{IPV4}(\s)?)*)" }
  }
}
```

Result,

```
      "path" => "/tmp/sample.csv",
"@timestamp" => 2017-08-24T05:00:08.093Z,
       "tmp" => "IN 192.168.11.2 IN 192.168.11.3",
  "@version" => "1",
      "host" => "host.ywlocal.net",
   "message" => "IN 192.168.11.2 IN 192.168.11.3"
```

Would this be possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the ruby filter for more advanced parsing:

```
filter {
    ruby {
        code => "event.set('ips') = event.get('message').scan(/\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\/)"
    }
}
```

Regexp is not 100% correct to match ip address but should work for your needs